# How to print a 2D array with fixed column width

Tags: arrays, ruby, printing, 2d

I have an array:

```
animals = [
  ["cats", "dogs"],
  ["verrylongcat", "dog"],
  ["shortcat", "verrylongdog"],
  ["cat", "dog"]
]
```

And I would like to display it nicely. Is there an easy way to make the colums a fixed width so I get something like this:

```
cats            dogs
verrylongcat    dog
shortcat        verrylongdog
cat             dog
```

`animals` is just an example, my array could also have 3, or 4 columns or even more.

Comment: Please clarify what the input array is.  Is it an array of text lines, or an array of arrays having 2 strings (words)?

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [`String#ljust`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-ljust):

```
max_cat_size = animals.map(&:first).max_by(&:size).size
animals.each do |cat, dog|
  puts "#{cat.ljust(max_cat_size)} #{dog}"
end
```

If you want more than one space just add the corresponding amount in the interpolation.

---

Assuming your array is *n × m* and not *2 × m*:

```
animal_max_sizes = animals.first.size.times.map do |index|
  animals.transpose[index].map(&:to_s).max_by(&:size).size
end

animals.map do |animal_line|
  animal_line.each.with_index.reduce('') do |animal_line, (animal, index)|
    animal_line + animal.to_s.ljust(animal_max_sizes[index].next)
  end
end.each { |animal_line_stringified| puts animal_line_stringified }
```

**Note:** The `to_s`es are used in case your arrays contain `nil`s, numbers, etc.

Comment: but what if my array has 3 , or 4 columns or even more ? :)

Comment: Then you don't make any assumptions like cat, dog, you treat your input data as an array of arrays of variable size.  You'd have to scan the data not only for the max size, but the max number of words (columns), and the max width of *each* of those columns' words.

Comment: so there isn't an easier , more readable way to do this ? :p damnit

Comment: @ndn thnx so much <3

Comment: @nbn I just copy pasted your code and it worked but for some reason I get the table twice! :P

Comment: @FroggyFreshh, what do you mean twice? Are you sure it isn't doubled in the array to begin with? (:

Comment: @nbnnvm fixed it , I've put your code into a def generatTable and called that into another def of mine like so : puts generateTable(animals) but appearantly I can't use puts in front of it :)

Comment: @nbn any chance you can briefly explain me the code ? :)

Comment: @FroggyFreshh, yea, it pretty much `ljust`s all the columns and concatenates them with `reduce`, starting with an empty string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111465/discussion-between-froggyfreshh-and-ndn).

Comment: Yes, I messed up. Have deleted my earlier comment and will soon delete this one.

Comment: @ndn now what if I have 2 colums of lenght "12" and one column of lenght 5 (the code you are suggesting here si'tn working for variable lenghts :) )

Comment: @FroggyFreshh, could you share your code [here](https://repl.it/languages/ruby). I just tried it and it worked.

Comment: @ndn sorry can't share the code :) here maybe somewhere else ?

Comment: can't make it runable tho but I think you can work with this ?[here](https://repl.it/CPxp/0)

Comment: @FroggyFreshh, could you add the final `array` you are invoking it with. I cannot deduce it from what you have given me.

Comment: @ndn the final array is basicly arr[] wich is a combination of 3 arrays (lenght 12, lenght12, length 5) I already tried with 3 of the same lenght and this worked but appearntly the last one with lenght 5 gives problems :/

Comment: @FroggyFreshh, could you embed it in the code. [Here](https://repl.it/CPxp/1) is an example of what you are describing and it works just fine.

Comment: @nbn could it be because there are nil values in there ?
you can find it [here](https://repl.it/CPxp/2)

Comment: @FroggyFreshh, yep, the `nil`s where problematic. [Here](https://repl.it/CPxp/4) is an updated version that works. I updated the answer as well.

Comment: @FroggyFreshh, happy to help. (:

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is with printf-style formatting.  If you know you will always have exactly 2 words in each line then you can do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

lines = [
    '   cats dogs',
  '       verrylongcat dog',
  'shortcat verrylongdog  ',
    ' cat dog      ',
]

lines.map(&:strip).each do |line|
    puts "%-14s%s" % line.split
end
```

Outputs:

```
cats          dogs
verrylongcat  dog
shortcat      verrylongdog
cat           dog
```

If you need to calculate the column width based on the data, then you'd have to do a little more work:

```
# as @ndn showed:
first_col_width = lines.map(&:split).map(&:first).max_by(&:size).size + 2

lines.map(&:strip).each do |line|
    puts "%-#{first_col_width}s%s" % line.split
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another attempt for a variable numbers of columns. Given this array:

```
animals = [
  ['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Fish'],
  ['Mr. Tinkles', 'Buddy', 'Nemo'],
  ['Calico', 'Butch', 'Marlin'],
  ['Ginger', 'Ivy', 'Dory']
]
```

We can calculate the width of each column via [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose), [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-map), [`length`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-length) and [`max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max):

```
widths = animals.transpose.map { |x| x.map(&:length).max }
#=> [11, 5, 6]
```

Based on this, we can generate a format string that can be passed to [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) (or its shortcut [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-25)):

```
row_format = widths.map { |w| "%-#{w}s" }.join('   ')
#=> "%-11s   %-5s   %-6s"
```

`%s` denotes a string argument, `11`, `5` and `6` are our widths and `-` left-justifies the result.

Let's try it:

```
row_format % animals[0]  #=> "Cats          Dogs    Fish  "
row_format % animals[1]  #=> "Mr. Tinkles   Buddy   Nemo  "
row_format % animals[2]  #=> "Calico        Butch   Marlin"
```

That looks good, we should use a loop and wrap everything it in a method:

```
def print_table(array)
  widths     = array.transpose.map { |x| x.map(&:length).max }
  row_format = widths.map { |w| "%-#{w}s" }.join('   ')

  array.each do |row_values|
    puts row_format % row_values
  end
end

print_table(animals)
```

Output:

```
Cats          Dogs    Fish  
Mr. Tinkles   Buddy   Nemo  
Calico        Butch   Marlin
Ginger        Ivy     Dory
```

#### More complex formatting

With a little tweaking, you can also output a MySQL style table:

```
def print_mysql_table(array)
  widths     = array.transpose.map { |x| x.map(&:length).max }
  row_format = '|%s|' % widths.map { |w| " %-#{w}s " }.join('|')
  separator  = '+%s+' % widths.map { |w| '-' * (w+2) }.join('+')

  header, *rows = array

  puts separator
  puts row_format % header
  puts separator
  rows.each do |row_values|
    puts row_format % row_values
  end
  puts separator
end

print_mysql_table(animals)
```

Output:

```
+-------------+-------+--------+
| Cats        | Dogs  | Fish   |
+-------------+-------+--------+
| Mr. Tinkles | Buddy | Nemo   |
| Calico      | Butch | Marlin |
| Ginger      | Ivy   | Dory   |
+-------------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Nice one, even though if you continue down that path you might as well use a [dedicated gem](https://github.com/tj/terminal-table).