# How do I print a 2D array with fixed column widths in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a Javascript array:

```
animals = [
  ["cats", "dogs"],
  ["verrylongcat", "dog"],
  ["shortcat", "verrylongdog"],
  ["cat", "dog"]
]
```

And I would like to display it nicely in the console. Is there an easy way to make the colums a fixed width so I get something like this:

```
cats            || dogs
verrylongcat    || dog
shortcat        || verrylongdog
cat             || dog
```

`animals` is just an example, my array could also have 3, or 4 columns or even more.

BTW - I'm shocked this question hasn't been asked, but I've looked everywhere and I can't find it.  I'm basically asking the same question as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122565/how-to-print-a-2d-array-with-fixed-column-width) but for JavaScript / JS.

Comment: Use for loops for each array. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for the table look in the console, you can use [`console.table()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table).

**Node.js support:**

- v10 - [native console.table](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_table_tabulardata_properties)
- before v10 - use the [console.table npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/console.table)

**Demo:**

```js
const animals = [
  ["cats", "dogs"],
  ["verrylongcat", "dog"],
  ["shortcat", "verrylongdog"],
  ["cat", "dog"]
];

console.table(animals); // look in the browser's console
```

To create a table on an HTML page, use nested [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create the rows for a table. Use [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to assign it to the table's body:

```js
const animals = [
  ["cats", "dogs"],
  ["verrylongcat", "dog"],
  ["shortcat", "verrylongdog"],
  ["cat", "dog"]
];

const rows = animals.map((r) => `
  <tr>
    ${r.map((c) => `<td>${c}</td>`).join('')}
  </tr>
`).join('');

target.innerHTML = rows;
```

```css
td {
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: 3px double;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="target"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I wanted it for debug in the console, but this is a good answer none the less.

Comment: Very nice!  I can't believe how long I've been using JavaScript and i didn't know about `console.table()`

Comment: Boo!  `console.table` doesn't work in NodeJS (at least in v8).  Do you have a trick for that too?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to log it to the console in NodeJS (which doesn't natively support `console.table(animals)` unless you're on v10.0+), do something like:

```js
const animals = [
  ["cats", "dogs"],
  ["verrylongcat", "dog"],
  ["shortcat", "verrylongdog"],
  ["cat", "dog"]
];

for (const animal of animals) {
    console.log(animal.map(data => data.padEnd(20)).join(" || "));
}
```

If you find that your data actually looks like this, then print it out using the code below:

```js
const animals = [
  {
    name: "dog",
    tail: true
  },
  {
    name: "cat",
    tail: true
  }];

console.log(Object.keys(animals[0]).map(data => data.padEnd(20)).join(" || "));
for (const animal of animals) {
  console.log(Object.values(animal).map(data => data.toString().padEnd(20)).join(" || "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you're going to need to define the maximum width of the first column: to get there, you need to iterate over the array and save the maximum length of the first element (the proposed solution uses `reduce()` to do this)

Then, you can iterate over the array once again and print each row with the right amount of padding (the proposed solution uses `map()` to do this, along with the `repeat()` method to reproduce the space character the desired number of times.

```js
const animals = [
  ["cats", "dogs"],
  ["verrylongcat", "dog"],
  ["shortcat", "verrylongdog"],
  ["cat", "dog"]
];

const maxLength = animals.reduce((currMax,el) => el[0].length > currMax ? el[0].length : currMax, 0) + 5;
animals.map(el => console.log(el[0] + " ".repeat(maxLength - el[0].length) + "|| " + el[1]));
```

EDIT: if the number of columns is > 2, then `maxLength` can be turned into an array of maximum lengths populated similarly to what has already been shown (i.e. by reducing the initial matrix). Then, the mapping needs to be updated so as to apply the spacing between columns accordingly.